# String doesn't update when passed to different Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to send two strings from Fragment A to Fragment B. Currently, i've implemented an `interface` listener like this...

**Fragment A Method:**

```
String arrayTitle1 = arrayList.get(Index).get("ArrayTitle1");
String arrayTitle2 = arrayList.get(Index).get("ArrayTitle2");

((TextFooterListener) getActivity()).onTextFooterListener(arrayTitle1, arrayTitle2);
```

I pass these strings to the Activity which sends them to Fragment B like this...

**Activity:**

```
@Override
public void onTextFooterListener(String arrayTitle1, String arrayTitle2) {

    FragmentB.arrayTitle1 = arrayTitle1;
    FragmentB.arrayTitle2 = arrayTitle2;

}
```

**Fragment B:**

They are then received and stored in Fragment B as public strings.

```
public String arrayTitle1;
public String arrayTitle2;
```

And in the `onCreateView` of Fragment B, i try to assign these strings.

```
arrayTitle1Footer.setText(arrayTitle1);
arrayTitle2Footer.setText(arrayTitle2);
```

But unfortunately, whenever Fragment A's method gets called, the `onTextFooterListener` doesn't seem to update the strings.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the values in Fragment B but never actually reassign the new values into the TextViews.

Change

```
@Override
public void onTextFooterListener(String arrayTitle1, String arrayTitle2) {
    FragmentB.setTitles(arrayTitle1, arrayTitle2);
}
```

And in Fragment B :

```
public void setTitles(String title1, String title2) {
    arrayTitle1 = title1;
    arrayTitle2 = title2;
    arrayTitle1Footer.setText(arrayTitle1);
    arrayTitle2Footer.setText(arrayTitle2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a mechanism you need to use to pass data to a Fragment. Please consider the following approach:

```
@Override
public void onTextFooterListener(String arrayTitle1, String arrayTitle2) {
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putString("array1", arrayTitle1);
    data.putString("array2", arrayTitle2);

    FragmentB b = FragmentB();
    b.setArguments(data);
}
```

Then in your `onCreateView` of FragmentB:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    arrayTitle1 = getArguments().getString("array1");    
    arrayTitle2 = getArguments().getString("array2");  

    arrayTitle1Footer.setText(arrayTitle1);
    arrayTitle2Footer.setText(arrayTitle2);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```